# How to get this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I am using two tables `emp` and `AM_ActionItems`

Structure of the tables are

`emp` table

- empid
- userid
- empemai

`AM_ActionItems` table

- AssignedBy
- AssignedTo
- assigndate
- duedate
- closedate

There is a no relationships but `AssignedBy = AssignedTo = userid`

```
select * 
from (select * 
      from AM_ActionItems as amp 
      where amp.DueDate > convert(date, dateadd(day, 0, getdate()))
        and amp.DueDate <= convert(date, dateadd(day, +1, getdate()))
        and amp.closeddate is null) as emp_det 
left outer join 
    emp on AssignedBy = userid
```

The sub query is working

Result is

```
 AssignedBy     AssignedTo          AssignedDate    DueDate        closeddate
Ponne.trichy    Syed Jameel Pasha   2014-03-27      2014-04-02       NULL
VenkatBiroje    Rekha               2014-03-28      2014-04-02       NULL
```

Problem is

`assignedby = assignedto = userid` in `emp` table how can I get all columns from the `emp` table ?

Comment: What do you want that the query is not producing?

Comment: All the records are showing i dont want to show all the records only that 4 records only

Comment: Isn't there an name field in emp table?

Comment: Expected result is 1  Ponne.trichy   ponne@gmail.com    2  VenkatBiroje     venkat@gmail.com     3        Syed Jameel Pasha      syed@gmail.com        4      Rekha               Rekha@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

i think this query will give you answer.

```
select emp.* 
from tbl_emp emp left join AM_ActionItems  amp
emp.userid=amp.assignedto self join AM_ActionItems  amp1
amp.assignedto =amp1.assignedto  
where amp.DueDate > convert(date, dateadd(day, 0, getdate()))
        and amp.DueDate <= convert(date, dateadd(day, +1, getdate()))
        and amp.closeddate is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to select all users that are either assigners or assignees of the inner query result? Then select from emp and use EXISTS to find out if matching records can be found.

```
select * 
from emp
where exists
(
  select * 
  from AM_ActionItems as amp 
  where emp.empid in (AssignedBy, AssignedTo)
  and amp.DueDate > convert(date, dateadd(day, 0, getdate()))
  and amp.DueDate <= convert(date, dateadd(day, +1, getdate()))
  and amp.closeddate is null
);
```